# Retrieve OUT parameters when SP's are invoked via callable statement in batch mode

Tags: java, jdbc, callable-statement

How to retrieve the values in OUT parameter when we invoke SP's via Callable statement in batch mode (executeBatch()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the OUT parameters when we run SP's in batch mode in Java.
We will get exceptions if we have configured out parameters for the SP's that are executing in batch mode.