# Retrieval of list of Output Parameter for a callable statement batch process

Tags: java, mysql

here this code will simply call my procedure and delete the user.

```
        CallableStatement CStatement = null;

        CStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call TESTPROC1(?,?,?)}");


        for(int i=0; i<usersToDelete.size();i++)
        {
            CStatement.setString(1,"delete");
            System.out.println(usersToDelete.get(i));
                CStatement.setString(2, (String) usersToDelete.get(i));
                CStatement.addBatch();
        }
        CStatement.executeBatch();
```

Now i need to get the third parameter that is the registered out parameter.

i cannot use this `CStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);` anywhere in the code

**i am confused how to get the output parameters from the batch process execution.**

i should not change the stored procedure.

is there any way to get the output parameters for this batch process?

Comment: *Why* can you not register the out parameter, given that that's clearly the most sensible thing to do? If you've got a very unusual requirement, you should give the reasons for it.

Comment: can you tel me where to place that CStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR); i tried it is not producing correct result

Comment: I'd expect you to place it just after `prepareCall`. It's not clear whether you can use that with batches, mind you - I don't think it makes much sense to use out parameters in a batch. (There may be a way of doing it, but I'm not aware of it.) But I thought you *couldn't* use `registerOutParameter`?

Comment: can you tell me how to get the output parameter returned by the procedure. i dont have any other solution now than this code. i should go for batch only. if you have any other idea of implementing it tel me

Comment: I've already said that I don't know how to get output parameters for batches - but that's what you should investigate. In fact, there's another question for that - I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retreive OUT parameters when SP's are invoked via callable statement in batch mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596748/retreive-out-parameters-when-sps-are-invoked-via-callable-statement-in-batch-mo)